What's the deal with Tex Live and cmunrm.otf?
I've been experimenting lately with XeLaTeX, and searching in particular for a font that looks very much like Computer Modern and can print polytonic Greek in addition to all the Latin characters any sane person might want to use. This was a somewhat frustrating quest (although I did eventually find a .ttf file that fitted the bill), until I stumbled on the following snippet:
\setmainfont[
    ItalicFont=cmunti.otf,
    BoldFont=cmunbx.otf,
    BoldItalicFont=cmunbi.otf,
    Numbers=OldStyle
]{cmunrm.otf}

This does exactly what I want. The only problem is, I can't understand why! I've combed through all the font files on my computer, and I can't find a cmunrm.otf file anywhere. Is this something that's just built into Tex Live? Looking at some other people's code, it does seem to be.

You might find this useful: https://ctan.org/pkg/newcomputermodern?lang=en

More information about the Computer Modern Unicode fonts is on their website, but you can find information about the TeX Live package, including a file list, on CTAN.

kpsewhich will show the location. In a default texlive 2024 you get
$ kpsewhich cmunrm.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/cmunrm.otf




I've combed through all the font files on my computer, and I can't find a cmunrm.otf file anywhere. Is this something that's just built into Tex Live?

Just curious: Why do you want to know where in your TeX distribution the OpenType font files might be located? I suggest you replace the code chunk
\setmainfont[
    ItalicFont=cmunti.otf,
    BoldFont=cmunbx.otf,
    BoldItalicFont=cmunbi.otf,
    Numbers=OldStyle
]{cmunrm.otf}

with
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}[Numbers=OldStyle]

This works under both LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. (Addendum posted in response to a  comment by @cfr: If your TeX installation is on Mac and you're using XeLaTeX, this approach requires that the CMU font be registered with the system, rather than just be available in the TeXMF tree. One way to register fonts with MacOS is to run the FontBook app.)
If you also need the sans serif and monotype font faces of the CMU family, all you'd need to do is add the instructions
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}

to the preamble. Aside: Neither CMU Sans Serif nor CMU Typewriter Text would appear to feature oldstyle numerals.

Note that \setmainfont{CMU Serif} without specifying variants also works fine in XeLaTeX, it chooses the right variant of CMU automatically for both Latin and Greek characters in the normal font, bold, italic, and bold+italic.

@Marijn - Thanks! I will adjust my answer.

my impression is that loading by filename is more reliable than doing so by font name, so that might be one reason - even if, in fact, it works fine either way in this case. and I don't see anything wrong with somebody being curious about why something works or wanting to know where a file is located. there are all kinds of reasons you might want to know this, but I think pure curiosity is more than enough. if this answer was addressed to me, I would be irritated at best. as it is, I'm vicariously irritated instead.

@cfr - Thanks. I certainly didn't mean to be patronizing. Speaking for myself (who else?), I find a one-line directive easier to master than having to learn four separate file names. (Naturally, I wouldn't say that \setmainfont or Numbers=OldStyle are hard to master.)

@Mico if I thought you intended it, I wouldn't have bothered commenting ;).

you might want to mention that \setmainfont{CMU Serif} will not work with XeTeX on macs unless the fonts are installed for the system rather than only being available in a texmf tree. (fontspec manual p10). (@Marijn)

@cfr - Thanks. I've added a sentence to take note of this fact.
